# how can we run multiple steps at a time in aws emr cluster ( Mainly running spark)?

Tags: apache-spark

we are submitting the spark jobs using step api of aws sdk. But a time there is only one job is in running state and other jobs are in pending state. If someone can help us to configure our aws emr cluster, where multiple steps can run in parallel